# Weird ArrayList Behaviour

Tags: java, arraylist, behavior

I create 3 objects of ChipSet and put them in an ArrayList. The arraylist does not contain the right values. The `debug messages` are quite clear on what happening but I have no explanation for this behaviour at all. Could someone tell me my error(s)?
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class WierdArrayBehaviour {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ChipSet> chipSetCombos = createComboExample();
        System.out.printf("\n\n---- Show created combolist ----");
        System.out.printf("\nCombo 1: " + Arrays.toString(chipSetCombos.get(1).getChips()));
        System.out.printf("\nCombo 2: " + Arrays.toString(chipSetCombos.get(1).getChips()));
        System.out.printf("\nCombo 3: " + Arrays.toString(chipSetCombos.get(2).getChips()));
    }

    private static ArrayList<ChipSet> createComboExample() {
        ArrayList<ChipSet> combos = new ArrayList<ChipSet>();

        System.out.printf("---- Creating possible combos ----");
        ChipSet combo1 = new ChipSet(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 1, 2});
        System.out.printf("\nCombo 1: " + Arrays.toString(combo1.getChips()));
        ChipSet combo2 = new ChipSet(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 1, 3});
        System.out.printf("\nCombo 2: " + Arrays.toString(combo2.getChips()));
        ChipSet combo3 = new ChipSet(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 1, 4});
        System.out.printf("\nCombo 3: " + Arrays.toString(combo3.getChips()));
        combos.add(combo1);
        combos.add(combo2);
        combos.add(combo3);

        return combos;
    }
}

class ChipSet {

    public static final int WHITE_VALUE = 1;
    public static final int RED_VALUE = 2;
    public static final int GREEN_VALUE = 5;
    public static final int BLUE_VALUE = 10;
    public static final int BLACK_VALUE = 20;

    public static final int[] VALUES = new int[]{WHITE_VALUE, RED_VALUE, GREEN_VALUE, BLUE_VALUE, BLACK_VALUE};

    protected static int[] chips;

    public ChipSet(int[] chips) {
        if (chips == null || chips.length != 5) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ChipSets should contain exactly 5 integers!");
        }

        // store a copy of passed array
        this.chips = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.chips.length; i++) {
            this.chips[i] = chips[i];
        }
    }

    public int getSum() {
        return chips[0] * WHITE_VALUE
                + chips[1] * RED_VALUE
                + chips[2] * GREEN_VALUE
                + chips[3] * BLUE_VALUE
                + chips[4] * BLACK_VALUE;
    }

    public int[] getChips() {
        return this.chips;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using `combo1` every time in `createComboExample`, and your indices are inconsistent in `main`.  Please note that Stack Overflow isn't intended a crowdsourced "spot my typo" service....

Comment: What are you seeing? What do you expect to see? You code printing the contents in main() calls get on indices 1, 1, 2 - you probably meant 0, 1, 2

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Sorry. Try again, I posted a wrong example.

Comment: Ok, please construct a complete test-case that we can directly copy-paste into an online compiler (e.g. http://ideone.com/), and tell us what the symptoms are.

Comment: Lol at the downvotes for not adding 2 imports and a class around it.

Comment: The downvotes are because you posted code with typos, didn't explain the symptoms, and didn't post code that could be compiled with zero effort.

Comment: And then had to post new code because your initial post had "wrong example".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Alright, I corrected the mistakes and made it compile-ready.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I meant typos with 'wrong example'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that your attribute `chips` is `static`, which means that it exists once per class.

Every time you create a new `Chipset` instance, you are overwriting the previous created `chips`.

**What can you do?** Don't declare it as `static`:

```
protected int[] chips;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are printing `combo1` every time. Change it to

```
System.out.printf("\nCombo 2: " + Arrays.toString(combo2.getChips())); // <-- 2
ChipSet combo3 = new ChipSet(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 1, 4});
System.out.printf("\nCombo 3: " + Arrays.toString(combo3.getChips())); // <-- 3
```

from

```
System.out.printf("\nCombo 2: " + Arrays.toString(combo1.getChips()));
ChipSet combo3 = new ChipSet(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 1, 4});
System.out.printf("\nCombo 3: " + Arrays.toString(combo1.getChips()));
```

**Edit**

Change

```
protected static int[] chips;
```

to

```
protected int[] chips;
```

As it is there are only one array of `Chips` for all of your instances.

Comment: @ManyQuestions Edited. Next time, for better help faster, post the correct code!

Comment: I've accepted another one because it made me understand better but nonetheless thank you very much.